# JQuery Mobile DateBox TimeBox make read only

Tags: jquery-mobile, datebox

I am using JQuery Mobile [DateBox](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/) with mode timebox as timepicker. It is working perfect. What I want is that I want the timepicket input to be readonly. It should only change the time on clicking the '+' or '-' buttons. I googled much and found solutions asking to add readonly attribute and lockinput. But nothing seems to be working. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code sample of my time picker.

```
<input id="service_time" class="create_formobj" value="<?php echo $date ? date('h:i A', strtotime($date)) : '' ?>" type="date" data-role="datebox"
                    data-options='{"mode": "timebox", "overrideTimeFormat": 12}' />
```

Comment: lockInput should make the original input read-only.  What behavior are you seeing instead?

Comment: Thanks Sage. But when i add the lock input there is no change.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What did was, I made the input field of pop up **readonly**. It will solve your problem
The readonly function can be add like this

```
$('.ui-datebox-dboxin input').attr('readonly', true);
```